# What is the difference between setting up react native apps as functions rather than classes?

Tags: react-native

Are there any advantages to writing react-native code like this,

```
export default class App extends Component { /* Code */ }
```

vs writing it like this,

```
export default function App(){ /* Code */ }
```

I've seen a lot of code on stack overflow written in the former, but much of the docs for react API's use the latter. I have also encountered issues with the former with things like react-navigation with it saying that I can't use hooks outside of a function, even when the hooks were used were inside of a render function.

Comment: Hooks cannot be used inside the render function. It should only be used in the functional components. Functional components and hooks are the future as per the react team. Write as many functional components as you can, and for the places, you can't resort to class components. With functional components, the code you write is much cleaner than that of class components.

Comment: So I should use the function App instead of the class App ?

Comment: Use the `function App`.